# How To Create Hover Regions On Sprite?

Tags: html, css, hover, sprite, regions

This code is intended to create two linked regions (for the purpose of hovering), on the top 50px of page, and next lower 50px.  So that, as you move your mouse vertically, you hit the two hovers, and the `img` shifts laterally.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
a {display:block; left:0; height:50px; width:300px;}
a#a1{top:50;}
a#a2{top:100;}
a img {position: absolute; top:0; left:0; width:300px;}
a#a1 img:hover {left: 50px;}
a#a2 img:hover {left: 100px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<a id="a1" /><a id="a2" /><img src="smiley.gif" />
</body>
</html>
```

I would also be fine with accomplishing this by re-positioning a background image, or with an image map.

How can I re-size a link (containing an `img`) so that my link hover only happens over *part* of the image?

Comment: Is this near to it? http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/FdxZ5/ I don't understand what you want, so I had a guess.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the img element will not be selected by `a#a1 img:hover` or `a#a2 img:hover` because img is not nested with either of the a tags.  For another, what you want is when you hover over some element other than the image itself, shift the image, but this is not something you can do in CSS alone to my knowledge.  You probably want to be using javaScript for this sort of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to give sprite images on the background of the tag.
Example:

```
.read {
        background: url('../../img/home/home-assets.png')no-repeat  0 0;
    }
.read:hover {
        background: url('../../img/home/home-assets.png')no-repeat  0 -50px;
    }
```

you have to define the background position in css.
for more information read these: http://www.ehousestudio.com/blog/view/css_sprite_navigation_tutorial , http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/